# OAuth authentication in twitch.tv with php

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I've seen similar Questions like this before but don't understand the correct way of doing it. Or rather the questions were always a little different.

The scenario: I have a site where the user should log in via twitch.tv
I have a button which refers him to this url

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
    &client_id=exampleclientid
    &redirect_uri=http://example.com
    &scope=user_read
```

I have censored redirect_uri and the client_id but basicly on this site the user needs to login into twitch or if he already is he can authorize that my application gets acess to "scope" here in this case "user_read" which is his email adress.

Now to my problem. When returning to my site my url will look like this

```
example.com/#access_token=exampleacesstoken&scope=user_read
```

example acess token is just a combination of numbers and letters which I need to acess private information like his email even his username.

Over this url

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken?oauth_token=exampletoken
```

I get acess to my needed information, but how do I grab the token from my url via php and delete everything after http://example.com to make it look good again.

The offical API documentation might be helpful and talks about CURL but I don't understand how it works and the PHP manual is very indepth.

https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API

Sorry if I'm taking the lazy way here, but I think I'm missunderstanding something big because I just have to make a simple grab of the URL

Answer (score 0):

From the Twitch documentation:

https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#implicit-grant-flow

> If the user authorizes your application, they will be redirected to
>   the following URL:
>
> `https://[your registered redirect URI]/#access_token=[an access
>   token]&scope=[authorized scopes]`
>
> Note that the access token is in the
>   URL fragment, not the query string, so it won't show up in HTTP
>   requests to your server. URL fragments can be accessed from JavaScript
>   with document.location.hash.

Comment: You should probably use this flow if you want your access token to be known by PHP:
https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md#authorization-code-flow

Comment: I don't understand this "POST https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token" is this a PHP function? How do I use it? thanks

Comment: Browsers do not send data in the URL hash to the server (PHP) - so you can access it with JavaScript or try a different authorization flow.

Comment: I was able obtain the string with "$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];" Did I do something wrong, because I got what I wanted and it worked on my live server.